# How can I restore Google Chrome after I deleted it on my rooted phone?

Tags: root-access, chrome-for-android, system-apps, delete

I have a rooted Mototrola G6 Play, and today I deleted google chrome because I don't use it, but once I deleted it a bunch of apps stopped working like LastPass and Coursera just to name a few...

I tried downloading it back from the play store but that didn't fix it.
I also tried making it a system application again using Lind2SD but it asks me to reboot and when I do it gets deleted.
I also tried manually installing the apk and placing it in /system/app/ and in /system/app/Chrome/ but that didn't work either!

How can I fix this problem?????

Edit: I was able to make chrome a system app again by changing the permission to rw-r-r after putting the apk in /system/app/Chrome but the apps are still broken!

Edit 2: I've just uninstalled and reinstalled the broken apps and they started working again!

Comment: Hi, looks like you've found the solution by yourself, which is great! Consider post it as a proper answer since [self-answering is not only allowed, but even encouraged!](//android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). Thanks!

Comment: Chrome may be installed on system partition but as far as I know it doesn't matter if you use it from system or as a regular user app. It does not have any system permissions and also does not require them.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling those broken apps?

Comment: @WrichikBasu yes and they actually worked, I edited the post and mentioned it, but some sicko edited it after and removed it

Comment: @SafwanLjd sorry, perhaps I should have been clearer. Unlike forums, and since this is [a Q&A site](https://android.stackexchange.com/tour), solutions belong to the Answers section, not the question. Please post your solution on the Answer below to make the question solved. Thank you.